# Run Google Script every other week

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google spreadsheet for payroll, with a script that needs to run every other week.  Right now, I'm running it manually.  I would like to use a time-driven trigger, but i can't figure out any combination that will do every other Thursday at 1am.  Anyone know a way this might be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use script properties to save properties about your script.

Set the following function to run every week

```
function runEveryWeek() {
  var runThisWeek = ScriptProperties.getProperty("runThisWeek");
  if (runThisWeek) {
    //do your task here
    ScriptProperties.setProperty("runThisWeek",false);
  } else {
    ScriptProperties.setProperty("runThisWeek",true);
  }
}
```

You'll have to initialize the "runThisWeek" property so that it is properly set.

Answer (score 5):

```
function createBiWeeklyTrigger() {
  // Trigger every other Monday at 06:00.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('function_name')
      .timeBased()
      .everyWeeks(2)
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
      .atHour(6)
      .create();
}
```

Comment: When will this fire off for the first time? Is it the first coming Monday?

Comment: I'm using this but I'm having problems with it, I'm setting a trigger to run it for the first time, but it's being triggered twice. Don't know why...

Answer (score 4):

you could prototype extend the date object to give you a week number and then choose to call only on even numbered weeks (or odd obviously)

```
Date.prototype.getWeekNumber = function() {
  var firstDay = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
  return Math.ceil((((this - firstDay) / 86400000) + firstDay.getDay()+1)/7);
}
```

and then in your weekly on a thursday trigger, wrap the whole lot in a conditional like

```
if (today.weekNumber() % 2 === 0) {
  // triggered function here
}
```

but I think i like Phil Bozak's on/off flag approach

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// The init() function runs once to set up the initial trigger.

function init() {
   ScriptApp.newTrigger("ThursdayTrigger")
    .timeBased()
    .atDate(2013, 3, 21) // Setup the first trigger on a specific date
    .create();
}

function ThursdayTrigger() {

  // 1. write the function code here

  // 2. delete the existing ThursdayTrigger

  var triggers = ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    if (triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() == "ThursdayTrigger") {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }
  }

  // 3. setup another trigger in the same function that triggers after 14 days.

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("ThursdayTrigger")
    .timeBased()
    .after(1000*60*60*24*14) // Alternate Thursday
    .create(); 
}
```

Comment: But then you have to deal with daylight savings, and the small offset that gets added by the fact that the trigger isn't created instantly. Eventually, it won't be running at 1am anymore. I prefer the prototype version.

Answer (score 1):

The ScriptProperties Library is now Depreciated. The [PropertiesService Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties) helped me figure out the solution below.

```
function runEveryWeek() {
  var scriptProps = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  if(scriptProps.getProperty('runThisWeek') == "True"){
    //do your task here
    Logger.log("tast executes");
    scriptProps.setProperty("runThisWeek", 'False');
  } else {
    Logger.log("task does not execute");
    scriptProps.setProperty("runThisWeek", 'True');
  }
}
```

I initially tried to set the values to booleans, but that caused an issue because the method `.getProperty()` has return type `string`. I tried to make the difference between the booleans and booleans-represented-as-strings explicit by using uppercase first letters.

You can test it out by checking the log after running it.

Answer (score 0):

I actually prefer JSDBroughton's answer, this can then be set to run on any given day of the week you want it to trigger and will only run items on even days. The other cool bit of this set-up is it lets you run a different set of things on the other week. For example, in my use case, on even weeks I make a backup of the document, but on odd weeks I reset the document to a template.

```
function triggerScriptonEvenWeeks() 
{
  var week = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "w") 
  if(week % 2 == 0)
  {
      //Even, anything here will trigger every other week
  }
  else
  {
      //Odd, leave blank for nothing to trigger
  }

}
```